# How to send mp3 data to ISpTTSEngineSite Write Api

Tags: c++, windows, text-to-speech, sapi

I am trying to implement a TTS Engine using SAPI 5 on Windows.
To make it simple, assume that I have a model trained which converts text to an mp3 file.
I need to stream/load this mp3 data to the ISpTTSEngineSite Write Api, but i get this error code "-2147024809"

```
std::ifstream file("C:\\Sample.mp3", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
std::streamsize size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

std::vector<char> buffer(size);
file.read(buffer.data(), size))

ULONG pcbWritten = 0;
hr = pOutputSite->Write(buffer.data(), size, &pcbWritten);
```

return result of Write call I get is -2147024809, I couldn't get the meaning of this
and obviously nothing got written and pcbWritten is 0 after the call.

Comment: That error code is E_INVALIDARG. Up to you to figure out what this means, since your code is several lines short of a [mre] we can run ourselves and fix. The documentation for `::Write` specifies that you need to specify the format in a call to `ISpTTSEngine::Speak`. But you seem to be blasting an arbitrary MP3 through this API. Are you sure you don't want a generic audio playback API instead of a TTS engine?

Comment: closest minimal reproducible example would be amazon poly. 
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-polly-tts-for-windows
In here, they get an output iostream buffer and sends this to the Write api, 
if i can replace this with a local mp3 output on my system and send it back to sapi engine to speak

Comment: The output from my model which does TTS is an mp3 file, i need to send the audio data back to the SAPI engine to speak. Simple example is native windows text to speech app.
As per the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms719570(v=vs.85) site

It says "Pointer to synthesized speech audio data."

Comment: The SAPI engine wants raw audio samples (sometimes also called "PCM") , not MP3. You will have to decode your MP3 file into audio samples. The Polly example [always returns 16kHz 16bit mono](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-polly-tts-for-windows/blob/master/PollyTTSEngine/ttsengobj.cpp#L443-L453) because it [requests that format from Polly](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-polly-tts-for-windows/blob/master/PollyTTSEngine/PollyManager.cpp#L97-L102)

Comment: I was thinking on similar lines of decoding the file for audio data, let me give a try on this approach

Comment: @Botje, an update, replacing .mp3 file with a .wav file works with the above posted code.  just that pitch is different, probably sample rate or something I need to look into.

Comment: Yes, the format of the wave file and the format you promise to sapi should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to my question:

The audio should be raw audio data, which the Write api is expecting.
As mentioned by @botje in the comments, .wav file is best suited.

The above logic still holds good as long it is Sample.wav and not .mp3.

For others, if mp3 is still the only option, there is a msdn doc on how to decode audio,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/tutorial--decoding-audio